# Execute relational query on tables from diffrenet servers

Tags: postgresql, nosql

Is it possible to connect schemas from remote server and use in web application with local ones. Suppose i have local shema with table 'users' and remote shema with table 'log' and i want to execute query like

```
select l.id from users u,log l where u.id=l.userId and u.name like 'Adam'
```

Is it possible to do it in postgesql or any other opensource database?

Comment: How is that question related to neo4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a foreign data wrapper.

For example, if you had two databases one of which is on a remote server, you can create a foreign server on the client and then reference tables and schemas on the remote server.

Please see the following documentation for doing this with two Postgresql servers.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/postgres-fdw.html

Comment: do you know same possibilities for other databases? I need to write overview, and trying to find all possible solutions

Comment: Yes.  There is a MySQL foreign data wrapper https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw

and an Oracle Foreign Data Wrapper and a substantial list of others: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Once 9.5 comes out, there may even be a built in facility for automatically discovering the schemas of the remote databases.  Until then you can use various tools.  One I wrote for extracting schema info from mysql as an example: https://github.com/no0p/my_etl